# Locating CK Editor and Sending text to it in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to locate CK editor for my project through Selenium Webdriver code(Java). But Whenever I try to use SendKeys() method it is not working for me. 
Below is the screenshot of CK Editor and HTML code.

[image]

And below is the code,

```
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe#scayt_8")).isEnabled())
{
  WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe#scayt_8"));  
  System.out.println("Frame Enabled");
  if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id = 'scayt_8']")).isDisplayed())           
  {           
    System.out.println("Frame Displayed");
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    iframe.clear();
    System.out.println("Clicking frame");
    iframe.click();
    iframe.sendKeys("Hello!!");
  }
}
```

Please help me to locate CK Editor and to Send text to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to switch to the inline frame to locate it.

```
WebElement editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("scayt_8"));

driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);

WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));

body.clear(); 
body.sendKeys("some text");
```

We provide techniques for working with editors in chapter 3 of our book Selenium WebDriver In Practice.

Comment: But I don't find any inline frame like body.

Comment: It worked nice, thank you. I'd like to add only one thing, after the sendKeys I had to run "driver.switchTo().parentFrame();", or else the rest of the test didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think iframe is being searched based on cssSelector but i think it is supposed to be based on id? which is scayt_8. Can you try with following code to fetch iframe instead of cssSelector:

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"))
```

Comment: I am able to locate frame using cssSelector but the thing is I am not able to send keys to it. Also there are 2 frames in the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Once you switch to iframe, try to locate webelement by **paragraph** tag name inside iframe, something like below:-

```
 WebElement body=driver.findElement(By.tagName("p"));
```

Then try to send keys using this webelement:

```
body.sendKeys("Hello!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")); driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); 
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")); 
tinymce.clear(); 
tinymce.sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!");;
```

---

---

This will help you to send text in CKeditor. Try this. It will work